# Upgrading PhoneGap from 2.9 to 3.3 — FileUpload issues

Tags: android, cordova, file-upload, phonegap-plugins

I've got an app that has been in production for iOS and Android for about a year now. I'm just getting around to upgrading from 2.9 to 3.3, and I'm running into some issues with file uploads.

I'm able to get the camera firing and every other API appears to be working well, but when it comes to the FileTransfer API, it's giving me errors... or, rather, non-errors. :)

I've got both the file-transfer and the file and the camera plugins defined in the config.xml, like so...

```
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.camera" />
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.file" />
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.file-transfer" />
```

... but when I go to upload, an exception is thrown, and the fail object I get is null throughout. No status code, no nothing. Every object property, null, null, null...

Looking at my IIS logs, it doesn't even appear like my endpoint is being posted to (I've got two different APIs I'm posting to, and neither of them is getting any hits).

Have there been any further changes to the FileTransfer API that I should be aware of? I'm reusing the existing code (barely modified from the tutorial in PhoneGap, which had been working for me for a good while), but I'm not certain there are any new changes I should be aware of. Code snippet looks like so, nothing fancy...

```
var photoFileName = photoLocation.substr(photoLocation.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);

var options = new FileUploadOptions();
options.fileKey = "adPhoto";
options.fileName = photoFileName;
options.mimeType = "image/jpeg";

var params = new Object();
params.ID = id;
params.photoState = thePhotoState;
options.params = params;
options.chunkedMode = true;

var ft = new FileTransfer();
ft.upload(photoLocation, Defaults.PhotoUploadService, photoUploadOK, photoUploadFail, options);
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In 2.9 the file transfer api is defaultly present but in v 3.3 you need to download manually download the necessary plugins.

Comment: I have included it, that's the thing. And it appears to get invoked — otherwise I wouldn't be getting the errors, but rather a "FileTransfer  is not defined" exception, methinks.

Comment: ok.. at which location in your cordova.js and cordova-plugin.js present.

Comment: It's on the head. And I'm exclusively using phonegap.js at this point.

Comment: means inside the www/phonegap.js or other ..